# Learning how to use SQL, how to fix isNull error?

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to test some codes in SQL, in this case one being to calculate the `Amount Due`.

Our database has a field that calculates it through this expression:

```
round(total_amount  - if( isNull( amount_paid ), 0,  amount_paid  )
    -  if( isNull( terms_taken ), 0,  terms_taken  )
    -  if( isNull( tax_terms_taken ), 0,  tax_terms_taken  )
    -  if( isNull( allowed ), 0,  allowed  )
    +  if( isNull( memo_amount ), 0,  memo_amount  )
    +  if( isNull( bad_debt_amount ), 0,  bad_debt_amount  ),
    2)
```

However when I try to use Excel to query this from the database, it states that the `isNull` function requires 2 arguments.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `isnull` expect two parameters

Comment: @maSTAShuFu IF() is a function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and there is no `IsNull()` or `if()` in (standard) SQL. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Excel isNULL expects single argument where as SQL ISNULL expects
   two arguments.
2. What you have shown us is EXCEL query. But won't
   work in SQL. In SQL, you will need to replace if(isnull(..), , ) with isnull(..., VALUE_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_USE_WHEN_IT_IS_NULL). So your SQL equivalent query is:

> ```
> round(total_amount 
>        - isNull( amount_paid, 0) 
>        - isNull( terms_taken, 0 ) 
>        - isNull( tax_terms_taken, 0) 
>        - isNull( allowed, 0 ) 
>        + isNull( memo_amount, 0) 
>        + isNull( bad_debt_amount, 0 )
>      , 2)
> ```

Comment: For example the first column Amount_paid,

Comment: I'd like to have it subtract the amount paid, but if the amount paid is null, to subtract zero. How would I write that?

Comment: yes, the query in my post does whatever you enumerated now. isnull(amount_paid, 0) evaluates to 0 if amount_paid is NULL. Amount_paid will be used if it is not null.

Comment: Please post your observations